# Why does an entity detach and how to deal with it?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

When

1. I fetch an entity from database via a stateless service,
2. then modify it in another bean and
3. then want to save it to database via the stateless service,

I notice the entity has been detached. I think because the stateless service's persistence context, the entity came from seized to exist.
But should one use a stateful service?
Now when saving I use `EntityManager#find(ClassOfDetachedEntity,PrimaryKeyOfDetachedEntity)` to get a reference to the entity in database and then assign the detached entity to it.
But is this the way?
Before I was only persisting copies to database, although I just wanted to modify the existing entry.

UPDATE (quick example to show where "detached"-problem occurs):

```
@Stateless
@Log
public class DatabaseService implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c").getResultList();
    }

    public void checkIfDetached(Object o){
        log.info("is detached: " + String.valueOf(!em.contains(o)));
    }
}
```

the beans log-statement will tell me, object is detached:

```
 @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class CategoriesBean implements Serializable {
        private Category testCategory;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
            testCategory = dbs.getCategories().get(0);
            dbs.checkIfDetached(testCategory);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detached entity is not much of a big deal, you can easily attach it back, you know. Actually, if I remember right from a lecure of *EJB 3  in Action*, JPA is designed in such a way that entities are attached for as *short* time as possible.

Simply [merge](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge%28T%29) (attach it back) your entity before performing any JPA operations on it:

```
em.merge(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons are:

1. you use a @Remote EJB in step 2 instead of a @Local.
2. the transaction context of the first EJB is different than the one of the second.

Easy to understand is that once the transaction is closed (committed or rolledback), the entity becomes dettached.

I do not have experience with JSF, but I think once you call ejb.getCategories() in JSF, the transaction in the EJB finishes, thus the entities get dettached. Also you didn't show how you injected the dbs: I hope you did that using `@EJB`. Besides I have read that (*at least @ManagedBean -annotated*) JSFs are not (default?) transactional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not using a @Remote EJB.

Answer (score 1):

That probably happens because when you call getCategories a new transaction is started because there was no transaction. When the function exits that transaction is completed and all entities are detached. Make sure you do all steps in a single transaction.